# Roslyn Code Diagnostic report other than text?

Tags: roslyn

Is it possible for a Diagnostic to return something other than simple text.

For example colourised text, or images? Or insert a Glyph in to the Editor Text

Comment: You would need to combine it with an editor classifier (or tagger + adornment layer)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no support for this. Diagnostics need to be able to be displayed in multiple places: not only the editor but error lists, command line builds, build server builds, etc. Restricting it to text ensures we can get the diagnostic everywhere it needs to be.